# Can I ask my senior to respond to my complaints?

Tags: communication, employer-relations, india

I have submitted some complaints to my superior regarding my staff but he doesn't respond to me. Whether I can ask him to respond to my complaints? I work under a Govt Body.

I sent through e mail and confirmed that he has received it at his end. It seems he wants to save the staff with a bad intention. I belong to Tripura in India.

Comment: Hello Pawan and welcome. The question is missing context. Please edit to add the following: 1. How did you submit your complaint (email, phone, hr intranet etc)? 2. Do you have regular status meetings with your supervisor? 3. Is this the first time you spoke with him/her about this? 4. What is your country / state?

Answer (score 3):

> *Whether I can ask him to respond to my complaints?*

Don't *ask* your superior to *respond to* your complaints - it *sounds* rude. Instead, *request* them for any *update* on your request (doubles up as a reminder, if your request fell through crack).

For anything non-critical, something along the line of:

> *"Dear Boss / Manager / Supervisor, Just checking with you whether you got some time to look into my previous request regarding the problems I was facing with my staff. If you can look into it and provide your comments, it'll be really helpful. Thanks."*

Should do the job.

If the case is more serious, and/ or you have a blocker that cannot be removed until you get a response, I'd suggest to setup a in-person meeting / appointment, and present your case there.